# How Notify Current user ,your insurance is going expiry within 5 days in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-notification

I am stuck in one problem and i want to notify current logged user for it's insurance will be expired within 5 days ago.

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
vehicle_no = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
chasis_no = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
make = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
insurance_no = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
insurance_date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)
insurance_expiry_date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)
```

Please help me to find exact solution

Answer (score 0):

You need something called `cron` or `cronjob`. Very easy to use is `django-crontab`.

Install:

```
$ pip install django-crontab
```

your_app/cron.py:

```
def my_scheduled_job():
  # check every Vehicle's insurance if is exactly 5 days from expiring
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django_crontab',
    ...
)

# it will execute this function at 4:59 every single day
CRONJOBS = [
    ('59 4 * * *', 'your_app.cron.my_scheduled_job')
]
```

Then activate / control / remove with commands:

```
$ python manage.py crontab add
$ python manage.py crontab show
$ python manage.py crontab remove
```

More details get on [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/django-crontab/).

Comment: I am appreciate your work, but it is not work

Comment: You might also try this:
https://pypi.org/project/django-apscheduler/